# How to get user's daily activity goals?

Tags: wear-os, healthconnect

In Wear OS 4, how can I obtain the user's daily goals for calories, steps, etc? I'd much rather avoid deprecated APIs such as [Google Fit](https://developer.android.com/health-and-fitness/guides/health-connect/migrate/migration-guide), phone-dependent APIs, optional apps, etc. I'm using Kotlin with SDK 34.

The data must be available because I can see it on my watch!

Bard and Bing both get it wrong (ie, their code won't build), and I can't find anything suitable in the Wear OS documentation. I would have thought that Health Services would have provided goal values, but I can only find event listeners that fire when goals are actually reached.

Comment: You don't. Goals are app-specific. Your app sets the goal it cares about, so you should know what it is, then the OS tells you when it's been hit based on the data it accumulated.

Comment: For Pixel Watches, daily goals are set in the Fitbit app on the phone. They're specified at user-level; they don't change from app to app. Those goals are available on the watch: various complications and tiles display them or their consequences, without the user having to re-enter them.

It used to be possible to get those values via Google Fit (https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-goals), but that's deprecated.

Comment: "For Pixel Watches, daily goals are set in the Fitbit app on the phone." ... by default because Google owns Pixel and pushes users to use Fitibit. But you can use different apps which would have their own goals.
"various complications and tiles display them ..." ... for example?
"it used to be possible to get those values via Google Fit" ... via the Google Fit API to access Google Fit data for a Google user.
I installed Fitbit and Google Fit - each has their own goals.